# Could accessed sites over an SSH tunnel be tracked by ISP?

Tags: isp, tunnel, ssh, proxy

I created an SSH tunnel and using it as SOCKSv5 proxy on Firefox. I checked `whatismyipaddress.com` and some other sites, they could not detect a proxy on my computer and shows my location on the server's country. However, I couldn't access to some sites...

Could the ISP track my traffic and block my access to a site while I am using SSH tunnel? If yes, how could they detect the traffic over an encrypted SSH connection?

Edit: If I login to my server and use `wget`, I am able to download the `html` content of the websites.

Comment: **"couldn't access to some sites"** ... what errors you get? Did you set up also DNS over SOCKS or you are using resolver provided by your local ISP?

Comment: I could not connect until the timeout while I can connect to other sites immediately. I am not able to change the DNS, but didn't the server machine send request to the DNS servers? Is it necessary to change it on my computer? Did I misunderstand the concept of SSH tunneling?

Comment: Uhm, are you registered here with your legal name? if so you give the turkish goverment insight in the fact you're looking up "illegal sites"

Comment: I know :( Lets see whether they use stackexchange or not :)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here, as are questions about home networking, networks over which you have no control, and bypassing network security or policies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNS is issued by default from your local host, not from the proxy, when using SOCKS (probably because SOCKS4 didn't support other way).

Make sure you have checked the checkbox "Remote DNS" in the Proxy configuration of the Firefox:

[image]